# Gaussian actions with no Bernoulli part

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras

In an unrelated research project I came upon an example of a *mixing* unitary representation $\pi: \mathbb{F}_{\infty}\to B(\mathsf{H})$ of the free group on infinitely many generators, such that no subrepresentation of $\bigoplus_{n\geqslant 0} S^{n}(\pi)$, the direct sum of symmetric tensor powers, is weakly contained in the left regular representation. In a sense, it means that no part of the associated Gaussian action acts like Bernoulli shift. It seems to me that Gaussian actions are usually thought of as a generalisation of Bernoulli shifts, sharing with them many properties, so at first sight the example seems odd. What is more, I have not been able to find such examples in the literature but I assume they must be known. So this is my question: where can I find information about such examples?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what is it that you're asking here. I think it is quite easy to come up with such examples. For example, take a highly transitive action of $F_\infty$ on a countable set $X$ such that the stabilizers of every $n$-tuple is non-amenable. Then (I guess that) $L^2(X^n)$, which is the $n$th tensor power (not even the symmetric version, which is a factor of it), has no subrep which is weakly contained in the regular. Moreover, I suppose this property is generic (in the Baire category sense).

Comment: @UriBader: I was just wondering if such examples appeared in the literature. From my perspective this behaviour is quite bizarre but I am not well versed in geometric group theory, so my intuitions might be quite different. That's why I asked here for a reference. Thank you for your nice example. But isn't it the case that these representations are not mixing? Since you assume that the stabilisers are infinite, it seems to me that many coefficients do not converge to zero.

Comment: You are right, these are not mixing (though they are weakly mixing). Here is a mixing action: embed $F_\infty$ as the commutator group of $\Gamma=F_2$ and $\Gamma$ as a discrete subgroup (say, a lattice) in $G=SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. Take any pmp action of $G$ on $X$ (e.g, $X=G/\Gamma$). I suppose $L^2(X^n)$ are far from the regular rep of $F_\infty$ (though I didn't check).

Comment: Thanks, I will have to digest this example. By the way, I don't really care if the examples are actions of $F_{\infty}$; examples of actions of other discrete groups would do.